# The bottom of the player capsule collider is going into the ground box collider

Tags: unity, c#, collision-detection, collider, character-controller

[image: Intersecting colliders]

The bottom part of the player capsule collider is going inside the ground collider. I am using a raycast for detecting whether the plauer is grounded; an object (sphere) that is present on the bottom bound of the capsule collider is responsible for firing the raycast.

[image: Player jumping with red ray extending below]

I think when the bottom part of the collider (including) the sphere is going inside the ground, my `isGrounded` variable is getting set to false, and the player character is transitioning from the landing to falling animation instead of running, which is not the desired behavior of course. I don't know why this is happening. I have been trying to find the solution for 2 days now and I can't seem to find the solution or reason behind the problem

- I am updating the size and center of the collider at runtime during different animations like jump, slide, and land (back to default size). I can provide code if needed.
- I am also moving the object responsible for the ray according to the size of the box collider using a `collider.bounds` and `extents` — will provide code if needed.

**More details and code about how ground detection works**

These two methods in the character control script are responsible for spawning and repositioning the object that fires ray on runtime. rayEmitter is a `GameObject` variable where prefab is added and Emitter is another `GameObject` variable. As you can tell RayEmitter object is spawning on the collider position.

```
  public void IntialSetup_of_RayEmitter()
    {
        Emitter = Instantiate(RayEmitter, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
        Emitter.transform.parent = transform;
        Reposition_RayEmitter();
    }

    public void Reposition_RayEmitter()
    {
        float bottom = cCollider.bounds.center.y - cCollider.bounds.extents.y;
        float side = cCollider.bounds.center.x - cCollider.bounds.extents.x;
        float front = cCollider.bounds.center.z + cCollider.bounds.extents.z;

        Emitter.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(side + 0.3f, bottom + 0.03f, front - 0.3f) - this.transform.position;
    }
```

these two methods are responsible for recentering and resizing the capsule collider at runtime, here I am using a bool `RepostionEmitter` as it turns true I am calling the reposition method **Above** on FixedUpdate, initially variable starts as false as it becomes true after updating size and center call reposition.

```
 private void UpdateCenter()
    {
        if (!UpdateNow)
        {
            return;
        }
        else if (Vector3.SqrMagnitude(cCollider.center - targetCenter_C) > 0.01f)
        {
            cCollider.center = Vector3.Lerp(cCollider.center, targetCenter_C,
                Time.deltaTime * CenterUpdate_Speed_C);
            RepostionEmiter = true;
        }
    }


    private void UpdateSize()
    {
        if (!UpdateNow)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            cCollider.height = Mathf.Lerp(cCollider.height, targetHeight,
                Time.deltaTime * SizeUpdate_Speed_C);
            RepostionEmiter = true;
        }
    }


 private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (StartRun)
        {
            if (isGrounded())
            {
                Grounded = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Grounded = false;
            }
        }

        ApplyGravity();
        RepostionEmiter = false;
        UpdateCenter();
        UpdateSize();

        if (RepostionEmiter)
        {
            Reposition_RayEmitter();
        }
    }
```

This bool method just a fire ray and detects the Grounded variable, I was also checking grounded or not using `Rigidbody` velocity but I had to remove it due to Dashing mechanisms during the dash especially if performed after the jump or double jump means in the air I don't want any different kind of velocity like gravity, etc to affect the dashing and it's forward force character just need to move forward during dash i am using `AddForce` for that, so you can imagine when I was doing that grounded variable was becoming true as i was messing with velocity during dash and due to that player was able to perform countless dashes in air and some other problems too.

```
 public bool isGrounded()
    {
        //if (Mathf.Abs(RIGIDBODY.velocity.y) <= 0.01f)
        //{
        //    return true;
        //}

        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(Emitter.transform.position, Vector3.down, out hit, rayDistance))
        {
            if (hit.collider.CompareTag("Ground"))
            {
                //Debug.Log(hit.collider.gameObject.tag);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

last thing and I think I should mention just in case, I am using something called a `Statemachine pattern` to control the logic/behavior of the character For example; this scriptable object containing code is present on all the animation state that needs to check if player is grounded or not.

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace EndlessRunning
{
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Object", menuName = "ScriptableObject/Ability/GroundDector")]
public class GroundDector : ScriptableObjectData
{
    public override void OnEnter(PlayerStateBase playerStateBase, Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo)
    {
    }

    public override void OnUpdate(PlayerStateBase playerStateBase, Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo)
    {
        if (playerStateBase.characterControl.Grounded)
        {
            animator.SetBool(HashManger.Instance.DicMainParameters[AnimatorParameters.Grounded], true);
        }
        else
        {
            animator.SetBool(HashManger.Instance.DicMainParameters[AnimatorParameters.Grounded], false);
        }
    }

    public override void OnExit(PlayerStateBase playerStateBase, Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo)
    {
    }
}
```

}

[image]

**That is how different player movements are being handled Overall my scene does not have anything related to that just objects that are responsible for** `cameraControl`, and `Spawning character` according to the selected character from character select scene These systems are completely separate, and decoupled from movement and has nothing to do with it.

**Character Inspector**

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried starting your raycast from higher up, so even a small overlap won't cause the ray to miss the ground surface?

Comment: yes I have tried it, Setting the value high too much causes the landing animation to trigger too quickly checking different values 0.5 seems to work less than that cause the issue mentioned above more than causes land to trigger way too early in mid-air, i will run more tests

Comment: You can also change the threshold at which you trigger the animation to counter any buffer space you add this way.

Comment: can you explain this threshold part a bit.. also maybe it has something to do with the speed of updating the box collider, I had the speed set to 5000 so it happens quickly, maybe this extra quickness pushes the collider into the ground without detecting collision.

Comment: To help you with that level of detail, we'll need more information in your question. Please edit it to include a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example. That is, all the code and scene setup steps a reader would need to follow to reproduce a simplified version of this problem, starting from a new, empty project. Once we can reproduce the issue, we can confirm which specific code or inspector/animation configuration changes will successfully resolve it.

Comment: alright thank you very much, I have edited the question check it out I have tried my best to explain everything and how it works and gave everything that is related to the problem or possibly connected with it and extra stuff that I thought would be essential for the level of detail. starting from a new empty project I could not understand this part what you meant by it, if you need me to create a new project with these simplified mechanisms and share it with you through GitHub or something then it will take time as you can see my project is quite complex at this stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I can't believe it took me 2 days to figure out what was the
   problem. solution is way too simple. All I had to do was to set the
   ray emitter object red sphere a bit higher so when the character
   hits the ground and the collider gets updated object does not
   penetrate the ground collider like it does in the picture above
   also have to increase the length of the ray.
2. Another issue is with the updating of the collider If the update
   size and center speed are set to a very high value like 500 or 5000
   then during the collider update emitter object gets pushed inside
   the ground.

[image]
[image]

now when the character hits the ground sphere stays a bit higher from the ground and does not return `isGrounded` false.

**For setting the sphere higher I just add 0.3 in the bottom position in the reposition method**

```
 float bottom = cCollider.bounds.center.y - cCollider.bounds.extents.y;
 float side = cCollider.bounds.center.x - cCollider.bounds.extents.x;
 float front = cCollider.bounds.center.z + cCollider.bounds.extents.z;

 Emitter.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(side + 0.3f, bottom + 0.3f, front - 0.3f) - this.transform.position;
```

***I hope it helps if anyone face similar issue in future***